# Finding sum a multi-dimensional array's reverse diagonal elements

Tags: c#

this is my multi dimensional array.

1-2-3-4

5-6-7-8

9-10-11-12

13-14-15-16

And i want find sum of reverse diagonal elements (From:right top To:left bottom) (4 -> 7 -> 10 -> 13)

Here is my code, it gives an error but i still can't find why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sketchboard
{
    class Program
    {

        static int reversediagonaladder (int[,] a)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for(int row=a.GetLength(0) ; row>0 ;  row--)
            {
                for(int column=a.GetLength(1) ; column>0 ; column--)
                {
                    if (row == column)
                        sum += a[row , column];
                }

            } 


            Console.WriteLine($"{sum}");
            return sum;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[,] a ={ {1,2,3,4},
                        {5,6,7,8},
                        {9,10,11,12},
                        {13,14,15,16 } };

            reversediagonaladder(a);

           


            Console.ReadLine(); // added for hold console on screen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code.  Hint: remember that array indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop starts with `a.GetLength(1)` or `a.GetLength(0)` in both cases this will resolve to `4` but there is no index with `4` since indexes start with `0`.

So index will be `0, 1, 2 or 3` which equals to a length of `4`.

To fix your problem you need to substract `1` from the length.

Currently you are also skipping the index `0`, I don't know why you are doing so, maybe it is an error aswell, to fix this you have to change the break condidtion of the `for` loop from `> 0` to `>= 0`.

This should work

```
for (int row = a.GetLength(0) - 1; row >= 0; row--)
{
    for (int column = a.GetLength(1) - 1; column >= 0; column--)
    {
        if (row == column)
            sum += a[row , column];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here a version which actually does what the question claims it does, it also gets rid of the double for loop which should run more performant

```
var column = a.GetLength(1);
for (int row = 0; row < a.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    column--;
    var item = a[row, column];
    sum += item;
}
```

Here you can see it in action:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/S5imGs

Comment: question sais "right top to left bottom".. you actually go right bottom to left top.

Comment: @Goodies - didn't bother to check if the code does what OP claims it does, just fixed the errors I found

Comment: Your remark about array bounds is correct. Only issue is.. it can't work. It won't go 4 -> 7 -> 10 -> 13 like Berke has specified. It will go 16-11-6-1 instead.

Comment: Error is gone when i put @RandRandom 's correction but still i cant find why algorithm dont work..

Comment: @BerkeTabak - check out my edit, seems this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with the `-1`, use [GetUpperBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=net-5.0) instead.

Here's an example doing as Self suggested with just one `for` loop:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] a ={ {1,2,3,4},
                {5,6,7,8},
                {9,10,11,12},
                {13,14,15,16} };

    int sum = reversediagonaladder(a);
    Console.WriteLine("sum = " + sum);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int reversediagonaladder(int[,] a)
{
    // code assumes a SQUARE matrix
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row=0, col=a.GetUpperBound(1); row<=a.GetUpperBound(0) && col>=0; row++, col--)
    {
        sum += a[row, col];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `// code assumes a SQUARE matrix` wouldn't know how going diagonal would work without a square matrix.

Comment: @RandRandom; It does diagonal and stop when either dimention ends.

Comment: @RandRandom You could pass in a Rectangular array, for instance.  The comment is really meant to draw attention to the fact that I'm not doing any checks to ensure the array is actually square.