# Loop diagonally in 2D array in c#

Tags: c#

I have below 2D array where I need to loop diagonally to find the similar value in adjacent and provide the counter for how many times it has occurred diagonally.

For e.g. below is 2d array

```
int[,] arrayGroup= new int[,] {
                { 99, 99, 0,  0,  0,  0  },
                { 0,  99, 0,  0,  0,  0  },
                { 99, 0,  99, 0,  0,  0  },
                { 0,  0,  0,  0,  99, 0  },
                { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  99 },
                { 99, 99, 0,  99, 0,  0  }
            };
```

so this array should give me output as 99 is present 4 times adjacent diagonally.

For this I am trying below code, but somehow I am not able to get the exact diagonal count

```
int diagonalCnt = 0;

for (var row = 0; row < arrayGroup.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (var col = 0; col < arrayGroup.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        if (arrayGroup[row, col] == 99 && arrayGroup[row + 1, col + 1] == 99)
            {

                diagonalCnt = diagonalCnt + 1;
            }
        
    }
}
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: What is the desired enumeration, please? Is it `99, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, ...`? From left bottom corner to top right one?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko desired enumeration is from left top to right bottom corner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66918879/finding-sum-a-multi-dimensional-arrays-reverse-diagonal-elements/66919042#66919042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You don't need to loop through the entire matrix. Assuming it's square of size `N x N`, you need to loop `N` times and check the `arrayGroup[i, i]` and `arrayGroup[i + 1, i + 1]` values
2. You compare the values explicitly to `1`. What you want to do it to compare the value to the next value: `if (arrayGroup[row, col] == 1 && arrayGroup[row + 1, col + 1] == 1)`

Here's the solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
    if(arrayGroup[i, i] == arrayGroup[i + 1, i + 1])
    {
        diagonalCnt += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are talking about Diagonal 2D Array, you mean a Square Only Matrix.

So to traverse through the diagonal you will need to loop from 0 to N - 1 because the diagonal will have N elements.

like this:

```
int max_count = arrayGroup.GetLength(0);
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
   if(arrayGroup[i, i] == 99)
        count++;

Console.WriteLine("Number of 99's is: " +  count.ToString());
```